# "1 through 3" VS "1, 2 and 3"

Tags: grammar

Are both of these structures grammatically correct, and is either of them preferable in something like a semi-casual email?

> I read chapters 1 through 3.
>
> I read chapters 1, 2 and 3.

Comment: Either is good.

Comment: For a short list like that it doesn't make any real difference but if you had read further into the book the 'through' form would be very useful. "I've read chapters 1 through 10" for example is much more succinct than '... chapters 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 and 10'. I do think that the 'through' form is more common in the US than the UK, though, where we tend to use either the ambiguous 'I've read chapters 1 to 10' or the unambiguous but more wordy 'I've read chapters 1 to 10 inclusive'.

Comment: @ BoldBen: I don't find 'I've read chapters 1 to 10' at all ambiguous.

Answer (score 3):

Both mean the same, though it you had read to chapter 20, you might chose the former rather than the latter out of concern for the exhaustion of your listener. In fact, I think if you said "I read chapters 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19 and 20, people would listen carefully assuming you were going to skip a number. It'd be unusual enough compared to "1 through 20", there would probably be an expectation of a deviation from the expected.

Another point worth pointing out is that "1 through 3" is actually an Americanism, in most of the rest of the English speaking world they would say "1 to 3".